# How are service nodes restored in CloudFoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

DEA's in CloudFoundry have a self healing infrastructure. Using the health monitor CF ensures that if a DEA crashes than a substitute should be spawned with the required runtime artifacts.

**But how about service nodes? Do they have a self healing infrastructure as well?** What if the VM having my MySQL instance crash? What will happen in this case - I can think of following options which one (if any) is correct?

1. Health Monitor detects that the MySql node is down. So it creates a new MySQL node and restores the data on this new VM
2. It is the responsibility of the MySQL node/provioner to monitor the node health and take necessary actions if the VM goes down
3. No self healing infrastructure - The app to which this MySQL node was serving will not work

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

There are no self healing services in Cloud Foundry, that is handled in the layer below Cloud Foundry - [BOSH](http://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh). However, broken services can't be self-healed the same way an app can, they require human intervention (inspection). If the service process has just crashed, it will be automatically restarted, but if you have a database corruption a human is needed to solve it.

The healing of services is dependent on the service itself, e.g. in MySQL you need to use a HA setup, and in Redis you have to use replication.

Comment: What is the responsibility of the Health Controller component in CloudFoundry?